# Is it possible to check existance of variables?

Tags: c++, c, variables, exists

Can we understand if there is a variable mentioned/created/exists ?
I mean something like that:

```
//..Some codes
int main(){
    int var1;
    float var2;
    char var3;
    cout << isExist("var1") << endl;//Or isExist(/*Something related with var1*/)
    cout << isExist("var2") << endl;
    cout << isExist("var3") << endl;
    cout << isExist("var456") << endl;//There is no variable named with var456
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: What's the bigger thing you're trying to do?

Comment: On a lighter note, look out for compiler error (you did not mention _runtime_). :-)

Comment: In this example, instead of `cout << isExist("var1")`, you could write `cout << var1`. If the code compiles, `var1` exists; if it doesn't compile, `var1` doesn't exist. -- The point is, at any point in the code, all the variables that exist are known at compile time, and nothing new is learned at runtime. So the question is why you would want to test something like this at runtime rather than at compile time.

Comment: I just wondered whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. C and C++ do not support [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: This goes quite beyond reflection

Answer (score 0):

Not in C/C++. But you could have a look at boost reflect library. http://bytemaster.bitshares.org/boost_reflect/

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, accessing a variable not defined will generate a compiler error. So, in a sense, that is inherent to how it works. You cannot do that at runtime, at least not as you are trying to do, and should not have need to - because you can't name new variables at runtime in the first place, so you should already know the variables there.

The only way to do this would be indirectly with macros. Macros can't check if a variable itself is defined, but a define could be paired with a variable definition and you could check for the define token.

```
#define A_VARIABLE 1
int a_variable = 60;
```

And later:

```
#ifdef A_VARIABLE
...
#endif
```

Like most macros, it is probably best to avoid this sort of behavior - however, I have seen it used to deal with platform-dependence of certain variables.

Dynamic memory is a different matter. Since you did not mention it, I will not go into it, but suffice to say it is a more complicated problem which proves the bane of many programmers and the source of many runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

The 'programming language C' is a human readable form of providing instructions to a computer. All names in the program have only meaning within the program text.

Upon compilation, the names are replaced with a symbolic reference to a storage location or function (execution starting point). Any symbol not found in the current complilation unit (object module) is marked for future resolution.

The object modules are combined (linked) into an executable, where all references to symbols not in an object module are resolved with locations in other object modules; otherwise the creation of the executable fails.

Since now any names have been replaced with references to storage locations and execution starting points, the executable doesn't know anymore about the names used in the program text to refer to its storage locations and functions.

Any ability to do so (the 'reflection' as user @Bill-Lynch calls it) would be 'bolted on' to the language/environment as a separate layer, for example provided by the debugging/development envionment.